# Инициализация роутинга вне зависимости от запроса клиента

Tags: javascript, веб-сервер, инициализация

Доброго времени суток.

Я пробую создать простейший **spa** в котором присутствует один базовый файл index.html в котором присоединены все скрипты и стили.

В секцию контента собираюсь подгружать html файлы без стилей и скриптов.

Роутинг планирую сделать с помощью sammy.js, но для упрощения можно представить, что буду вручную прописывать window.hitory.

Опять же, для упрощения - никаких фреймворков, библиотек не рассматриваю, к определённому типу сервера не привязываюсь, интересует подход.

Структура может быть следующая:

- index.html `// файл с подключёнными файлами app.js и styles.css;`
- app.js
- styles.css
- pages `// папка в которой находятся файлы с обычным html, без лэйаутов, подключения скриптов и стилей;`

  - main.html;
  - about.html;
  - contact.html;

Когда пользователь заходит на ://example.net, или ://example.net/index.html вопросов не возникает.

Вопрос появляется, если пользователь изначально прописывает в адресной строке адрес, отличный от базового, например ://example.net/pages/main.html

Но, мне нужен изначально index.html, для прогрузки всех скриптов(стилей).

Мне лучше конфигурировать сервер, ведь прописывать скрипт в каждом темплейте, так это уже не spa? Как это происходит на практике? Всё отправлять на app.js, в котором инициализировать index.html, а потом смотреть на запрос?

Comment: На практие в spa не загружаются html файлы (main.html, about.html). Загружаются данные, на основе которых происходит построение html. В вашем случае вам надо, что бы сервер всегда отдавал index.html на ://example.net/pages/main.html. Потом в index.html смотрите, какой url и грузите то, что вам надо.

Answer (score 0):

Я решал похожую задачу, додумался написать [виртуальный роутер](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/tree/master/lib/virtual-router), роутер, не использующий реальную адресную строку браузера. Браузер всегда находится на `index.html`, что на мой взгляд, очень удобно, так как можно раздать проект с Github Pages. Для разбора шаблонной ссылки с параметрами он использует модуль `path-to-regexp`, парсер ссылок, использующийся в Express.

```
<Router>
  <Route url="/" component={BriefPage}/>
  <Route url="/list" component={ListPage}/>
  <Route url="/one/:id" component={OnePage}/>
</Router>
```

Роутер использует React, однако, `webpack` или обвязка `create-react-app` при работе с ним не нужны: для сборки используется только TypeScript Compiler. Благодаря этому вы можете вручную управлять своими зависимостями без npm, что удобно в малых студенческих проектах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете посмотреть spa и исходный код, написанный с его применением, [по ссылке](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/blob/master/packages/form-generator-app/STUDENTS.md)